# How can I divide degrees greater than 360 to be within the 360 degrees?

Tags: rotations

I've got a rotation of something in degrees, however this rotation can be greater than 360 or less than 0.

How can I multiply/divide this to be within 360? For example, 1800 to be turned into 360, 900 turned into 180, etc?

Comment: Subtract 360 till you reach the range you desire.

Comment: Any more efficient methods?

Comment: Divide by 360 and the remainder will be your answer.

Comment: @antman 900 divided by 360 is 2.5, which isn't correct.

Comment: Woah! I said the **remainder** will be the answer. So you can't have decimal answers. You will have to use the actual division method(primary school one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1**

Subtract 360 till you reach the range you desire. (by antman from the comments)

**Method 2**

If programming codes can be used then the [modulus operator](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) ' % ' can be used to find the remainder.

Example:
 900 % 360=180
General form:
$x$%360=[value]

Modulus operator gives the remainder when we divide the degrees by 360.

**Reason**

After a complete rotation (covering 360 degrees) we come back to zero.

Comment: Great! I'll use the second method!